# How to restore the latest version of a pre-release NuGet package as part of an Azure DevOps build

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget

I'm creating a pre-release NuGet package as part of an Azure DevOps build, and pushing it to the internal Azure DevOps feed.  This is working fine.

As part of the same pipeline, I want to use this newly-pushed package so that I can restore it and run some tests.  I can't seem to find a way of getting the latest version to be restored.

In the project into which I want this to be restored, I've set the package reference to have a wildcard:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyNewNuGetPackage" Version="0.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When packing, I'm using this step in my pipeline:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Pack
  inputs:
    command: pack
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
    requestedMajorVersion: 0
    requestedMinorVersion: 1
    requestedPatchVersion: 0
    packagesToPack: 'src/**/*.csproj'
    packDestination: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

This creates a package with a version number of MyNewNuGetPackage.0.1.0-CI-20211111-084008.nupkg

This is correctly pushed to my internal feed, but when I try and restore the packages for my target project, using this step:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: 'MyTargetProject.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'my-local-feed-id'
```

Then I get this error:

> (Restore target) ->
>
> /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyTargetProject.csproj
> : error NU1103: Unable to find a stable package MyNewNuGetPackage
> with version (>= 0.0.0)
>
> /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyTargetProject.csproj
> : error NU1103:   - Found 2 version(s) in
> feed-my-local-feed-id [ Nearest version:
> 0.1.0-CI-20211111-084008 ]
>
> /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyTargetProject.csproj
> : error NU1103:   - Found 0 version(s) in NuGetOrg

So the task can see that there's a pre-release version there, but I assume it's only looking for non-pre-release (i.e., stable) releases, given the error 'Unable to find a stable package'.

How do I do a NuGet restore as part of this build that restores the latest pre-release package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the dependency version in the csproj file like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyNewNuGetPackage" Version="0.*-*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

See [this specification](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Support-pre-release-packages-with-floating-versions) for more details.

Comment: Yep, that was exactly what I needed to do.  Thanks!